# Copying a set of data from External worksheet including Hidden Rows

Tags: excel, vba

So I would like to copy an external Set of Data from an external worksheet (source), but the source has a filter and has hidden some rows. Now the output i am hoping is that it copies all the data including the hidden ones. below is my code , where "ROCV" is the internal Destination sheet, and "PROJECT DETAIL" is the external data source:
(by the way, my first time here and also a very amateur VBA coder so please bear with me :D)

```
Option Explicit
 
Sub CopyOutput()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim Ret1, Ret2
 
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
 
    '~~> Get the File
    Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select file")
    If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub
 
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1, UpdateLinks:=False)
    wb2.Sheets("PROJECT DETAIL").Range("a7").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=wb1.Worksheets("ROCV").Range("A7")
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

 
 
    Set wb2 = Nothing
    Set wb1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ShowAllData**

```
Sub test()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim Ret1, Ret2
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant
    
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    
    '~~> Get the File
    Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select file")
    If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1, UpdateLinks:=False)
    Set Ws = wb2.Sheets("PROJECT DETAIL")
    
    If Ws.FilterMode Then
        Ws.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    '** Receives values into a two-dimensional array, and assigns the values of the array back to the target worksheet.
    vDB = Ws.Range("a7").CurrentRegion
    wb1.Worksheets("ROCV").Range("A7").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    
    'Ws.Range("a7").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=wb1.Worksheets("ROCV").Range("A7")
    'wb2.Sheets("PROJECT DETAIL").Range("a7").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=wb1.Worksheets("ROCV").Range("A7")
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    
    
    Set wb2 = Nothing
    Set wb1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Dy.lee!
this works so fine and i am amazed!
except for one of the changes. 
as you see below, the "set wb2" string has an "updatelinks" properties to disable request for update of links function while opening the file. however i think with your added "Set WS", it is now asking to find where to link the formula. i can simply cancel i, but still i am hoping to have it completely disabled while the macro is running.can you help on this one more time? :D
again i appreciate this so much!


`Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1, UpdateLinks:=False)
Set Ws = wb2.Sheets("PROJECT DETAIL")`

Comment: Now i know, it should have "a paste as value" somewhere in this section but i can't seem to figure where and what is the correct code. apparently, some of the hidden rows that it copied has external link sources that should be disregarded. 
'Ws.Range("a7").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=wb1.Worksheets("ROCV").Range("A7")'

Comment: @BoyDespasito, If you are trying to retrieve a value, it is convenient to use an array. Corrected the answer.